# Python ARIMA model only sees two values

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting, arima

**Hi all,**

I'm trying to make an arima model in Python.

I have a data set with MasterDate, AREA and QTY.

In the beginning of the code, I'm filtering my excel file by filtering on AREA and Dropping column GRPCODE.

I've created one training and one valid set.

Training set is 01-12-2020 (and back)

My valid set is 01-11-2020 and futher.

> X_train = df2[df2['MasterDate'] <= '01-12-2020'].groupby(by='MasterDate').sum()

> X_train.reset_index(inplace = True)

> X_valid = df2[df2['MasterDate'] >= '01-11-2020'].groupby(by='MasterDate').sum()

> X_valid.reset_index(inplace = True)

**(full code below).**

My code only returns two days. I've asked for 500 days.
See piture
[Two forecast days in data. Other points are 134.67](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2GeZ.png)

[Forecast plot (Bold blue point is my validate set)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4edvr.png)

Can anybody help? I don't know why my code only sees two values

```html
########################################################################################################
######################################### Packages / libraries #########################################
########################################################################################################
import os                                  #provides functions for interacting with the operating system
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns



########################################################################################################
################################################ ARIMA #################################################
########################################################################################################
# To change scientific numbers to float
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':'{:f}'.format})

# Increases the size of sns plots
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(8,6)})

from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import linear_model

import pmdarima as pm
from pmdarima.model_selection import train_test_split

from pandas import to_datetime

import itertools
import warnings

import datetime
from datetime import datetime
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

########################################################################################################
######################################### Read and Filter CSV ##########################################
########################################################################################################

#Read CSV from Boels shared folders (with check)
df = pd.read_csv (r'\\nlstd116qvs01\QlikView\QDF\99.Shared_Folders\7.Export\B2-371\12098.csv',sep = ';')
print (df) 

df=df.drop(columns=['GRPCODE'])

##Select only AREA's. Scope!
df.loc[df['AREA'].isin(['NL Z5','NL Z1','NL Z2','NL Z3', 'NL Z4'])].to_csv(r'C:\Users\dassej\Documents\Analytics\Eindstage\export_dataframe.csv',index = False, header=True, encoding='utf8')

#Read edited CSV from Boels 
df2 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\dassej\Documents\Analytics\Eindstage\export_dataframe.csv',sep = ',')
print (df2)

df2['MasterDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['MasterDate'], format = '%d-%m-%Y')
print(df2)

X_train = df2[df2['MasterDate'] <= '01-12-2020'].groupby(by='MasterDate').sum()
X_train.reset_index(inplace = True)


X_valid = df2[df2['MasterDate'] >= '01-11-2020'].groupby(by='MasterDate').sum()
X_valid.reset_index(inplace = True)


print('X_train Shape', X_train.shape)
print('X_Valid Shape', X_valid.shape)

#X_train['MasterDate'].unique()


# filtering the train data
au = X_train
au2 = au
print(au)

#filtering the valid data
au_v = X_valid
au_v2 = au_v

# set the date into index
au2.set_index('MasterDate', inplace=True)
au_v2.set_index('MasterDate', inplace=True)

# Setting the Index for 6 years
index_3_years = pd.date_range(au_v2.index[-0], freq='D', periods = 500) #500 days


# Running ARIMA with random numbers
model = ARIMA(au2, order=(0,0,1)) 
model_fit = model.fit()

# print summary of fit model
print(model_fit.summary())

# The default is to get a one-step-ahead forecast:
print(model_fit.forecast(steps=5))
fcast1 = model_fit.forecast(steps=500) #500 days forecast

# Saving ARIMA predictions
#fcast1 = model_fit.forecast(7)[0] #-> NOT working
print(fcast1)


# Passing the same index as the others
fcast1 = pd.Series(fcast1, index=index_3_years)
fcast1 = fcast1.rename("Arima") 
print(fcast1)


# Ploting the predictions
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
chart = sns.lineplot(x='MasterDate', y='QTY', data = au)
chart.set_title('AU')
fcast1.plot(ax=ax, color='red', marker="o", legend=True)
au_v2.plot(ax=ax, color='blue', marker="o", legend=True)
plt.show()

#Printing the AI
print('The MSE of ARIMA is:', mean_squared_error(au_v['QTY'].values, fcast1.values, squared=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your code, you set the ARIMA order to (0,0,1). That means the Moving Average component `q` is set to 1. An MA model can only forecast `q` steps into the future. Your model will therefore be only able to forecast one step into the future. If you want to predict more steps, you either need to include more lags on `q` or you need to build an Autoregression model with the `p` component.

But to be honest, forecasting 500 steps into the future is a very hard task. The order of all ARIMA components should not be higher then 10, meaning even in that case you only take the last 10 lags in your forecast. If you forecast 500 steps, that means from step 11 and onwards your forecast is based on forecasted values. It does not matter how good you model fits to the data, if you try to forecast 500 steps the forecast will be very bad.